# regex cookie validator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that would mach if the cookie values are valid, but I can't figure out how to match multiple characters and make a property required...

This is what I've made so far...
`((name=\w;)|(value=\w;|expires=0-9)|(secure=true|false))&&(domain=\w;)`

This would be a valid string:
`name=test1;value=abc123;expires=14325;domain=github.com`

The string would be invalid if no domain is specified or there are additional parameters than `name` (string), `value` (string), `expires` (number), `secure` (boolean) or `domain` (string)

Comment: do you care about order? if the domain is before the optional values?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem for regex. An algorithm would be better. What programming language are you using?

Comment: no, the order is not important. I just found that there has to be 3 required params: name, value and domain

Comment: @LeoAso it's javascript. I'm trying to validate an input field

Answer (score -2):

**I HAD TO REWRITE MY ANSWER instead of deleting it. It's is because I didn't read the question properly... I deserved my previous downgrade.**

@Valip

I tried to create a regex that meets your requirements, but I only think of a solution that implies creating a single regex wich capture each KeyValue pair (Key=value) and use javascript to analyze each of them, according to your requirements:

The regular expression is:

```regex
((\w+)=([\d\w-_.]+))
```

and the Javascript is:

```js
const regex1 = /((\w+)=([\d\w-_.]+))/igd;
const str1 = 'expires=14325;value=abc123;MyField=false;domain=git-1hub.com;name=test1;domain=git-2hub.com;';
let array1;

while ((array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Found [${array1[0]}]. Next starts at ${regex1.lastIndex}.`);
  //TODO: VALID each scenary;
}
```

The output:

```
> "Found [expires=14325]. Next starts at 13."
> "Found [value=abc123]. Next starts at 26."
> "Found [MyField=false]. Next starts at 40."
> "Found [domain=git-1hub.com]. Next starts at 60."
> "Found [name=test1]. Next starts at 71."
> "Found [domain=git-2hub.com]. Next starts at 91."
```

With each element, it could be easier to handle each element. For example, it captures `MyField=false` which is an invalid KVP.

I tried another regex, selecting each KVP pair allowed  into the string, but it excludes the others KVP, and it is wrong:

```regex
((name|value)=[\w\d]+)|(expires=\d+)|(secure=false|true)|(domain=[\d\w-_.]+);
```

Output:

```
> "Found [expires=14325]. Next starts at 13."
> "Found [value=abc123]. Next starts at 26."
> "Found [domain=git-1hub.com]. Next starts at 60."
> "Found [name=test1]. Next starts at 71."
> "Found [domain=git-2hub.com]. Next starts at 91."
```

In this case, the string `expires=14325;value=abc123;MyField=false;domain=git-1hub.com;name=test1;domain=git-2hub.com;` has an invalid KVP (`MyField=false`) which is not detected and is prone to errors.